# random value from lognormal distribution in perl

Tags: perl, random, numbers, distribution, logarithm

I'd want to randomly pick numbers from a lognormal distribution that I can define myself. I want to use perl for this. There's probably a really simple solution for this, using only a couple lines of code, but I can't find anything just now, and when I try to think about it, my thoughts get stuck somewhere... So, I'd appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  (Even if it required more than a couple of lines.)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I basically tried putting this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Generating_log-normally_distributed_random_variates to code but I only got 0s all the time, so I probably had some values wrong.. Or I might need something completely different for what I'm trying to do... I really have no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start [at CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Math-Random-OO-0.21/lib/Math/Random/OO/Normal.pm) to get a normal generator, then apply the formula on the Wikipedia page you linked to by replacing `Z` with a call to `Normal`.

Or you could just grab a lognormal generator from CPAN...

Comment: Wouldn't there be an easy way to this without using CPAN? I feel like it should be so simple but I just can't seem to get my mind around it. I kind of got around my initial problem already (without using lognormal randoms), but I'd still like to know how one would do this kind of thing by coding everything themselves.

Comment: The normal distribution is fairly challenging to generate from scratch.  If you want to do so, check out [Box-Muller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-Muller) or [Marsaglia's Polar Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method). However you do it, you need to generate a normal before you can transform it to a log-normal.